# How to learn writing a v8 dynamic link library for `rust_v8`?

Tags: android, v8, deno

I want to compile it using the latest version ：[librusty_v8_release_aarch64-linux-android.a](https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/releases/download/v0.42.1/librusty_v8_release_aarch64-linux-android.a).
But my programming background is weak.

#### My purpose

I want to compile `deno` into `android`, and then use the `function` of `deno FFI Type`, but `librusty_v8_release_aarch64-linux-android.a` has not been updated in `rust_v8:V0.42.1`. The new `deno FFI Type` cannot be used in `android`, so I want to compile the new dynamic link library, how can I do it?

#### I tried

I have tried to use the `rust_v8` binding containing `android` in a higher version of `deno`, but it also fails to compile, and the prompt: `v8` dynamic link library function is incomplete.

Further information here:
https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/issues/1045

Answer (score 0):

fine!
The above problem is the problem I compile on the x86 architecture. When I switch to the arm64 architecture, there is no such problem. It should be a problem with creating V8 snapshots.